# Piedra, papel o tijera en Java, no funciona

Tags: java

Estoy iniciandome en Java y tengo un ejercicio sobre hacer el juego de piedra papel o tijera y el caso es que cuando los jugadores eligen que sacar deberia salir si ha sido empate o si ha ganado alguien, pero noo me aparece nada. Tambien si hay empate deben repetir hasta que gane alguien. Edito : si escribo minusculas no me aparece nada, cuando escribo mayusculas si me salen esta vez pero mal

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String seleccion1, seleccion2;
    boolean correcto;
    do{
        System.out.println("Elige, Piedra(P) Papel(L) o Tijera (T)"+"\n"+
                "Jugador 1: P/L/T");
        seleccion1=teclado.next();
        System.out.println("\nJugador 2: P/L/T\n");
        seleccion2=teclado.next();
        correcto=true;
        if(seleccion1.equals("P") || seleccion2.equals("P")) {
            System.out.println("Es un EMPATE!!");
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("P") && seleccion2.equals("L")) {
            System.out.println("GANADOR JUGADOR 2");
            correcto=false;
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("P") && seleccion2.equals("T")) {
            System.out.println("GANADOR JUGADOR 1");
            correcto=false;
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("L") && seleccion2.equals("P")) {
            System.out.println("GANADOR JUGADOR 1");
            correcto=false;
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("L") && seleccion2.equals("L")) {
            System.out.println("Es un EMPATE!!");
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("L") && seleccion2.equals("T")) {
            System.out.println("GANADOR JUGADOR 2");
            correcto=false;
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("T") && seleccion2.equals("P")) {
            System.out.println("GANADOR JUGADOR 2");
            correcto=false;
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("T") && seleccion2.equals("L")) {
            System.out.println("GANADOR JUGADOR 1");
            correcto=false;
        }
        if(seleccion1.equals("T") && seleccion2.equals("T")) {
            System.out.println("Es un EMPATE!!");
        }
    }while(!correcto);
}}
```

Este es el codigo que he hecho.

Comment: Para que no tenga en cuenta las mayusculas y minusculas y te compare cambia `.equals` por `.equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para comparar Strings de manera  `CASE insensitive` (que no tenga en cuenta si es mayus o minus) cambia `.equals` por `.equalsIgnoreCase`.

También puedes pasar el `String`del input a mayúsculas:

`seleccion1.toUpperCase().equals("S")`

---

Respecto a tu código:

Deberías de usar `if/else` para que si entra en una opción no siga buscando.

```
if(){
    ...
} else if(){
   ...
} ...
```

Ademas en el primer `if` tienes un `or` -> `||` por lo que si escribes "P" en uno de los 2 casos te saldrá empate aun que solo lo haya sacado uno de los 2.

```
if(seleccion1.equals("P") && seleccion2.equals("P")) {
```

Como mejora, y algo que suele costar pensar es ¿cuantos `if` necesitas?
En tu caso son 3 resultados diferentes, por lo que lo puedes y deberías de hacer con 3 `if`.
Como comenta [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) en el comentario y por el chat me ha sugerido,
Que la validación de estos inputs debería de ser lo primero en realizarse y ya que sabemos que siempre van a ser inputs "validos" entonces la comparación del empate es mas sencilla `seleccion1.equalsIgnoreCase(seleccion2)`:

```
if(seleccion1.toUpperCase().matches("P|L|T")
    && seleccion2.toUpperCase().matches("P|L|T")){
    if(seleccion1.equalsIgnoreCase(seleccion2)){
        System.out.println("EMPATE!");
    } else if((seleccion1.equalsIgnoreCase("P") && seleccion2.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
        || (seleccion1.equalsIgnoreCase("L") && seleccion2.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
        || (seleccion1.equalsIgnoreCase("T") && seleccion2.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))){
        System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Alguien está haciendo trampas! solo es valido: P/L/T");
}
```

Y como mínima mejora tambien puedes inicializar `correcto` en el mismo punto en el que la declaras:

```
boolean correcto = true;
```

Comment: no es mas mucho mas facil el empate asi? seleccion1.equalsIgnoreCase(seleccion2)?

Comment: Tambien recomiendo que controle si el usuario ha metido realmente un caracter y así te evitarias futuras comprobaciones. Sería otro dowhile

Comment: Me funciona perfecto y agradezco la explicacion

Comment: @Angel_Perez recuerda aceptar la publicacion si te sirvio!

Comment: gbianchi true, editada! Gracias! :)
@Angel_Perez Revisa de nuevo la respuesta, ahora es mas correcta.